# Strange processes and high CPU in Meteor App

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

As usual, I deployed my app using Meteor UP.

Using htop, I noticed a high CPU% for the process:

`/opt/nodejs/bin/node opt/Idretis/app/main.js`.

It also shows 6 times and some other processes show also more than once.

It doesn't seem to be really normal to me. Do you have any idea ?

Here is the screenshot of htop:

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I think you got old instances, you will have to restart the box if possible to get rid of them or just kill them.

Comment: My app is hosted on a Ubuntu VPS and I have a the same situation even after `reboot now`. Killing the instances either doesn't change the situation...
Now I have more than 15 times the line `/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`...

Comment: you might need to submit a github issue to meteor-up to get more help about this one, not sure without more information really. Maybe the issues tab on github already had similar cases

Comment: I did [https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/598](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/598)...